# My site is showing an error that I believe is generated by an unrelated website. Is this a DNS issue?

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, hosting, domain-registration

I recently transferred my domain to GoDaddy ([garrypettet.com](http://garrypettet.com)). Everything seemed to go smoothly. I have a server with [DigitalOcean](http://digitalocean.com), managed by [ServerPilot](http://serverpilot.io). The website was fine until a few moments ago.

Now when I visit garrypettet.com, I am shown an error page saying that the site is in maintenance mode. The odd thing is that the title of the page says "Vapor Hub International" which, from what I can see, is a totally unrelated website to me. The page that is being displayed I don't think is being served up by my server.

I have no idea how to debug this problem. Is it an oddity with DNS? I have restarted my server to no avail.

Comment: Right now your domain is resolving to the ip address 95.85.51.99. Only you know if that's correct or not. If not, then log into your DNS control panel (at GoDaddy) and correct it.

Comment: Thats correct. I have a few subdomains also pointing at that IP address (e.g: thoughts.garrypettet.com) and they display correctly. Typing the IP 95.85.51.99 actually shows the correct page but typing garrypettet.com shows this weird Vapor Hub message. I've no affiliation with Vapor Hub and can't figure out why this is displaying

Comment: When I open my browser to garrypettet.com I get a page with an icon/button in the middle that states "You have arrived.". When I click the icon/button I'm redirected to laravel.com.

Comment: I see the test page for the Laravel PHP framework. Is that what you're expecting?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What DNS server are you using on the computer you are trying to visit the website with? Perhaps you are using a server that doesn't have the updated DNS record for your domain.

```
nslookup www.garrypettet.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.garrypettet.com canonical name = garrypettet.com.
Name:   garrypettet.com
Address: 95.85.51.99
```

That is what I get on my machine. Is it possible to change your DNS settings to use Google DNS servers (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4)?

Another thing you can do is make an entry in your HOSTS file for your domain. That will avoid querying your DNS server, and that can be used as a temporary fix until it is updated.

Create a line at the bottom of your HOSTS file like this one, using this [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/).

```
95.85.51.99 garrypettet.com
```

Comment: The problem was that I had been using my iPhone to tether my laptop for a few days and the DNS hadn't propagated to my iPhone. I waited another 24 hours and the problem solved itself. Still unsure as to how "Vapor Hub International" factored into things...